# Any good template to write down server access details?

Tags: untagged

I wonder how other fellow sysadmin, web developers manage their inventories. I usually write down all access details in text files, not following any practice or convention.

Can someone tell me, if there's such practice or convention about saving server access details, etc on documents ? For future reference, etc. To give it to future developers working on-site, or sysadmin, etc.

Comment: atlassian confluence, wiki's, passpack, git repo. there are plenty of options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Wiki sounds good! I'll also have a look on confluence. Just wondering about the git repo ? I often leave a README file there with all this information. Not sure how safe that is, but, the truth is that the repo URL also needs to be got somewhere else I guess. Like, if I'm hit by a car and someone is picking up all the projects I worked in or something...

Comment: Do you mean access logs (like user x accessed server y at day z for 20 minutes) or simply password management?

Comment: I've written a more formal answer below. I think the OP means keeping track of IP addresses, usernames, passwords, URLs that sort of stuff.

Comment: Password management mostly!

Comment: For password management I'd suggest something like KeePass.

Comment: Static documentation is doomed to be perpetually out of date. Gather live data from running systems, and use network infrastructure protocols that have database functionality (DHCP and DNS servers) as your "IP address list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of options, at the end of the day it depends how you want to access the data (and how sensitive the information is).

Here are a few examples to get you going.

- Password Management, something like PassPack https://www.passpack.com/en/home/
- A wiki, something like http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki
- Confluence https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence is popular with enterprise
- Your own private git repo (this will keep a history of all your changes, even if you delete a commit). Can be useful for some situation. Remember you can restrict access to git repos however you please, and they're good at tracking changes!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at opensource or free: you should look at [passpack](https://www.passpack.com/en/products/?ref=home%7Chome%7Cbtsplash) or [keepass](http://keepass.info/) as others have mentioned.

For commercial: take a look at [Device42](http://www.device42.com/). It can track all server asset info, along with passwords for each server(and even applications). You can do shared password management between different users, keep history of all the old passwords and also run reports based on expiry dates.

Disclaimer: I am one of the founders behind Device42.